# PHP: getimagesize returns false for uploaded file

Tags: php, file-upload

I know there are many similar questions but none of them addresses this particular problem.
Anyway, I'm trying to get the uploaded image dimensions before getting it saved on the server. Bellow is the code that I tried so far

```
print_r($_FILES);
$temp = getimagesize($_FILES['aaiu_upload_file']['tmp_name']);
print_r($temp);
var_dump($temp);
```

it outputs:

```
Array
(
    [aaiu_upload_file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Screenshot_4.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /home/username/tmp/phpN4uRRA
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 19765
        )

)

bool(false)
```

So, is there something I'm doing wrong? your help is highly appreciated.

My PHP Version is `7.3.1`

Answer (score 0):

As in php getimagesize [Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

use this to get image dimension :

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($_FILES['aaiu_upload_file']['tmp_name']);
echo $width.'x'.$height;
```

Comment: As mentioned in question, `$temp = getimagesize($_FILES['aaiu_upload_file']['tmp_name']); print_r($temp);` returns `bool(false)` instead of an array

Comment: maybe because your image file is either corrupt or its not an image, or maybe because your server setting.

Comment: I can proceed uploading `move_uploaded_file()` without checking the height/width

Comment: getimagesize purpose is to get the size of an image like dimension. so if the file is not an image or not readable then will return bool(false). move_uploaded_file is to moves an uploaded file to a new location, either an image or not.

Comment: hmm you might be right, but as you see the image type in question it says `image/png`, moreover, logically, there should not be a permission issue, because, its being moved by `move_uploaded_file()` and I can read the image from the server without any issue.

Comment: $_FILES type variable only return file type by their last extension, not actual content type. if you create text file and use png extension, it still recognize as image/png. and that can lead to file injection if file upload not handle carefully.

Comment: The file is not corrupted and is PNG, its working on another server (same code)

Comment: then you must check server configurations, check php error log, check for missing plugin, or fresh install the webserver again. good luck.