# How to use getImagesize() for an uploaded file before it gets saved into the server?

Tags: php, file, file-upload, image-uploading, getimagesize

Given that [getImagesize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) requires a string and `$_FILES['myfile']` is an array, I've tried to get to the temporary folder and the file uploaded there in order to get the image size, but I do get an error.

### This is the error that I get:

> Warning:
>   getimagesize(/home/everymorning/public_html/tmp/phpNFuAMD/images.jpeg):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/everymorning/public_html/demo1.php on line 48

### And here is what I've tried:

```
$string = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'].'/'.$_FILES['myfile']['name'];

echo getimagesize($string);
```

And [if I try to use the temporary path directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585829/php-getimagesize-returns-false-for-uploaded-file), I still get an error:

### If I use:

```
getimagesize($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
```

### I get:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   /home/everymorning/public_html/demo1.php on line 47

Comment: Why don't you try it after [move_uploaded_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)?

Comment: getImageSize always return an array... why do not try `filesize( )` which returns size of file in bytes

Comment: `$_FILES['myfile']['name']` is only the file name as send by the client, the temporary file has nothing whatsoever to do with that string. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']` is the name of the temporary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `getimagesize($fileName)` has following things-

```
Array ( [0] => 667 
        [1] => 184 
        [2] => 3 
        [3] => width="667" height="184" 
        [bits] => 8 
        [mime] => image/png );
```

You are trying to echo an array- error of `Array to string conversion`. Infact echo could not print array instead `print_r` and `var_dump` are the those can print the info of array.

To calculate the size of an image you can simply calculate by multiplying height width and bits used to represent a pixel and following arithmetic expression can give you size of an image in bits.

```
 $imageInfo = getimagesize($fileName);
 $size = $imageInfo[0] * $imageInfo[1] * $imageInfo['bits'];
```